# Exception in thread main error?

Tags: java

Why am I getting this error? I need to read from the text file and allow them to login if the password and username match but I keep getting an error " no line is found ". But my text file has lines

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Program7_4Part2 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(new File("accounts.txt"));

    // PART 2

    ArrayList<String> userNames = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> passwords = new ArrayList<>();

    // read data from file
    while (fileInput.hasNextLine()) {
        userNames.add(fileInput.next());
        String line = fileInput.nextLine();
        String[] userName = line.split(" ");
        userNames.add(userName[0]);
        passwords.add(userName[1]);
    }

    // login
    System.out.println("Login.");
    System.out.println("Username: ");
    String userNameLogin = fileInput.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Password: ");
    String pwLogin = fileInput.nextLine();

}
```

}

Comment: Well, you just looped until your file doesn't have a next line, and then you try to read the next line... What do you expect to happen in this situation?

Comment: how would I fix that?

Comment: You can't.  By definition if you read *all* the lines in a file, there are none left.

Comment: then how would I make this work? By not using a while loop?

Comment: In the part after `//login`, why do you want to read from the file at all?  Wouldn't you want to read from standard input?

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you showed the actual error.  But I suspect you are getting the error from this line:

```
String userNameLogin = fileInput.nextLine();
```

You've already read through the entire file in the `while` loop.  So here there is no next line left to read.

But you probably want to read from System.in here, not from the file.

Comment: that fixed it! My next issue is adding a login verification message if they enter the correct username and pw. I understand I will need if statements for that but how would I compare their input to what the text file says?

Comment: That is a very broad question.  If you don't know how to compare strings, you should google it or locate a basic Java tutorial or reference book.